# Detetar data do utilizado com PHP

Tags: php, data

Como é que detecto através de `php` a data do utilizador?
Ou seja, eu sei como detetar a data, mas fazer a comparação com a data do servidor, logo não fica certo devido aos diferentes fusos horários.
Deixo em baixo o meu codigo:

```
<?PHP
    $current = date("d/m");
    $date    = "14/02";
    if ($current == $date){
        echo “qualquer coisa”;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Você não consegue capturar a data do usuário através do PHP.

Comment: Então isso não é possivel?

Comment: Diretamente não. Você só conseguirá essa data utilizando `JavaScript`. No `php` só é possível utilizando POG (programação orientada a gambiarra). Você poderá pegar o IP e, através dele, buscar as informações de que cidade/estado ou país ele está acessando, daí você conseguirá a data.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime::getTimezone() - Retorna o fuso horário corresponde a um DateTime informado
DateTimeZone::__construct() - Cria um novo objeto DateTimeZone

Para mais informações consulte os links a baixo
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.settimezone.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_default_timezone_set.asp

Comment: Mas esta informação é referente ao servidor, não ao usuário. Se eu estiver no Brasil e o servidor no EUA, o resultado estará errado.